# HHVM Type Checker error on preg_match_all

Tags: hhvm

HHVM type checker tend to produce an error when the argument/parameter of a function was not defined.

`preg_match_all('/regex/', 'string', $matches)` will produce an error on the `$matches` as `Undefined variable: $matches`.

`preg_match_all` fills the `$matches` parameter as an object.

Previous method of solving similar issues was to set `$matches = null;` or equivalent before the function was called. However, since `foreach` will be used, I was not able to set the variable in null or object.

Is there a standard on solving this issue in HHVM? I have not seen any solution in hhvm doc.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$matches = null` is the usual solution I've used for this.

> Previous method of solving similar issues was to set `$matches = null;` or equivalent before the function was called. However, since `foreach` will be used, I was not able to set the variable in null or object.

Unless I misunderstand, you can set it to null outside the loop -- the typechecker only cares that it's defined in the right scope. For example,

```
$matches = null;
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
  preg_match_all('/regex/', 'string', $matches);
}
```

---

Another option is to use [`HH_IGNORE_ERROR`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/typechecker/special#hh_ignore_error). The error you're getting from an undefined `$matches` should have an error code -- I don't have it in front of me, but assuming the error code is 4321, you can do this:

```
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
  /* HH_IGNORE_ERROR[4321] Write some comment here */
  preg_match_all('/regex/', 'string', $matches);
}
```

I think just setting the variable to null is much cleaner and clearer though.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$matches` will be filled with an array, not an object, you can also set it to an empty array instead.

```
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/regex/', 'string', $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
  ...
}
```